# Data Binding Android Recycler view

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am using android data binding and following is the class which I am using to set Variable

```
public class DayTemp extends BaseObservable implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("dt")
    long date;
    @SerializedName("pressure")
    double pressure;
    @SerializedName("humidity")
    long humidity;
    @SerializedName("temp")
    Temp temp;
    @SerializedName("weather")
    ArrayList<Weather> weathers;
    @SerializedName("speed")
    double speed;
    @SerializedName("deg")
    double deg;
    @SerializedName("clouds")
    double clouds;

    @Bindable
    public long getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(long date) {
        this.date = date;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.date);
    }

    @Bindable
    public double getPressure() {
        return pressure;
    }

    public void setPressure(double pressure) {
        this.pressure = pressure;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.pressure);
    }

    @Bindable
    public long getHumidity() {
        return humidity;
    }

    public void setHumidity(long humidity) {
        this.humidity = humidity;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.humidity);
    }

    @Bindable
    public Temp getTemp() {
        return temp;
    }

    public void setTemp(Temp temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.temp);
    }

    @Bindable
    public ArrayList<Weather> getWeathers() {
        return weathers;
    }

    public void setWeathers(ArrayList<Weather> weathers) {
        this.weathers = weathers;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.weathers);
    }

    @Bindable
    public double getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(double speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.speed);
    }

    @Bindable
    public double getDeg() {
        return deg;
    }

    public void setDeg(double deg) {
        this.deg = deg;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.deg);
    }

    @Bindable
    public double getClouds() {
        return clouds;
    }

    public void setClouds(double clouds) {
        this.clouds = clouds;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.clouds);
    }
}
```

As In this POJO class I am able to set all the values to my recyclerview bt I can't access the weathers arraylist and also not able to get the fields related to it.

```
public class Weather extends BaseObservable implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("id")
    long id;
    @SerializedName("main")
    String main;
    @SerializedName("description")
    String desc;
    @SerializedName("icon")
    String icon;

    @Bindable
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.id);
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getMain() {
        return main;
    }

    public void setMain(String main) {
        this.main = main;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.main);
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.desc);
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.icon);
    }
}
```

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  >

    <data>

        <import  type="com.weatherappforleftshift.currentlocation.DateUtils"/>

        <variable
            name="daytemp" type="com.weatherappforleftshift.currentlocation.model.DayTemp"/>


    </data>

           <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/weather_status"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:text="@{HOW TO SET TEXT HERE FROM weathers list}"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</layout>
```

I want to set Icon and Description from weather class to my recyclerview.

How to achieve this in the item layout????

Comment: @pskink I'll go through it...thnx

Comment: @tynn asking for data binding only,not able to access arraylist from a class

Comment: _HOW TO SET TEXT HERE FROM weathers list_ is no valid information. At least provide code how you would convert a list of `Weather` to a `CharSequence`. A utility method or something maybe...

Comment: List of weather is custom arraylist with text and icon,which is in DayTemp class,which is my root class for recyclerview item.I tried to access that list like this @{daytemp.weathers.get()},but can't access the exact element in weathers.

Comment: Consider using [`ObservableArrayList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableArrayList.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this github project

https://github.com/arunshankar87/triptrial

I have handled the data binding for a recyclerview

More specifically the below 2 files will be of interest

https://github.com/arunshankar87/triptrial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/arunshankar/triptrial/MyAdapter.java

https://github.com/arunshankar87/triptrial/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/row_layout.xml

Comment: First of all thnx for the input but I want to access beyond that.Right now I am doing this @{daytemp.weathers.get()}, but I want to get the data related to weathers,weathers is an **arraylist**.

Answer (score 0):

add in your VM:

```
@Bindable
public String getWeathersText() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < weathers.size(); i++) {
        builder.append(weathers.get(i).getText);
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

and in your layout xml:

```
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/weather_status"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
      app:weathersText="@{daytemp.weathersText}"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I didn't checked it but i think it should help...

Comment: I solved it by using two data variables, thnx for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a variable/instance of the "Weather" class in the layout xml.

```
<variable
        name="weatherData" type="<packageName>.Weather"/>
```

You can use this "weatherData" object to retrieve any "Weather" class property

You just need to pass the weather object to the xml from your RecyclerViewAdapter class.

```
bindind.setWeatherData(whetherList.get(position));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to skin this cat. But you specifically speak of Binding, so let's do this the right way then :).

You will need a few things, but don't worry, much of this is one time boiler plate that you can reuse on every recyclerview over and over again. Thats the beauty of it.

1)RecyclerView in your layout

2)Generic Binding Adapter for the RecyclerView

3)JMVStatic Adapter for conversion types and setup

4)Interface for communicating to your RecyclerView's Adapter

That's pretty much it, so let's get into the code.
BTW, if you don't care to understand it, you can pretty much copy and paste, although it may do more things then you need. Also there are other ways to handle the click events as well. You can nest those into the Row layout file themselves with no issue.

STEP 1:
THE INTERFACE CLASS

```
    interface IBindingRecyclerView<T> {

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // EXTERNAL METHODS
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    fun getRowLayoutResourceId(): Int
    fun getBindingModelId(): Int
    fun getActionButtonResourceId(): Int
    fun onItemClick(model: T, position: Int)
    fun onItemLongClick(model: T, position: Int)
    fun onActionItemClick(model: T, position: Int, holder: BindingRecyclerViewAdapter.BindingHolder)

}
```

NOTE* you may or may not care about click handlers, long clicks, or action items. An action item would be a sub button that is not considered a row click.

STEP 2:
THE JVM STATIC BINDING ADAPTERS

```
   object BindingAdapterMethods {

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // MEMBERS
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private var TAG: String = SSGlobals.SEARCH_STRING + "BindingAdapterMethods"



    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // METHODS
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /**
     * This makes sure that the interface and observable list is set in the recyclerView's adapter. If the adapter is null,
     * then a new one is created.
     * @param view
     * @param iBindingRecyclerView
     * @param list
     */
    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter(value = ["bindRcvInterface", "bindRcvList", "bindRcvPlusInterface"], requireAll = false)
    fun setBindingRecyclerViewProperties(view: RecyclerView, iBindingRecyclerView: IBindingRecyclerView<*>, list: ObservableArrayList<*>?, iBindingRecyclerViewPlus: IBindingRecyclerViewPlus<*>? = null) {
        if (view.adapter == null) {
            val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(view.context)
            view.layoutManager = layoutManager
            view.invalidateItemDecorations()
            view.addItemDecoration(VerticalItemDecoration(0))
            view.adapter = BindingRecyclerViewAdapter<Any?>()
        }

        val adapter = view.adapter as BindingRecyclerViewAdapter<*>
        adapter.setIBindingRecyclerView(iBindingRecyclerView, iBindingRecyclerViewPlus)
        if(list != null) {
            adapter.setList(list)
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE* This is simplified for adding just one adapter, you will have many many as your binding usage increases. You can ignore the recyclerViewPlus parameter, just delete it. I use that for high customization of the layout and setting more data into children ui of the row ui as you know databinding requires you to walk the tree. But I digress.

STEP 3: 
IMPLEMENTATION IN ACTIVITY OR FRAGMENT

```
class MyListFragment : BaseFragment(), IBindingRecyclerView<YourListModelType> {
   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   // MEMBERS
   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   private lateinit var mBinding: FragmentYourItemListBinding
   private var mYourItemModelList : ObservableArrayList<YourListModelType> = ObservableArrayList()


   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   // LIFE CYCLE OVERRIDES
   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
       mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_your_item_list, container, false)
       mBinding.fragment = this
       mBinding.iBindingRecyclerView = this
       return mBinding.root
   }
   override fun onResume() {
       super.onResume()
       fillYourListOfItems()
   }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // PROPERTIES
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    fun getYourListItemModelList() : ObservableArrayList<YourListItemModelType> {
        return mYourItemModelList
    }


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // IBINDINGRECYCLERVIEW OVERRIDES
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    override fun getRowLayoutResourceId(): Int {
        return R.layout.row_your_layout_file
    }
    override fun getBindingModelId(): Int {
        return BR.YourListModelType //defined in the xml coming up next
    }
    override fun getActionButtonResourceId(): Int {
        return -1 //if you aren't using, just return -1 or remove from interface
    }
    override fun onItemClick(model: YourListModelType, position: Int) {
        //handle the click of your item, launch a detail activity, whatever you need
    }
    override fun onItemLongClick(model: YourListModelType, position: Int) {
        //same as above, but if not using, you can remove from interface
    }
    override fun onActionItemClick(model: YourListModelType, position: Int, holder: BindingRecyclerViewAdapter.BindingHolder) {
        //if not using, you can remove from interface
    }


}
```

Ok, all the setup is in place, now the simple part. The xml binding. :)
First Declare your variables at the top.

STEP 4 VARIABLE DECLARATION

```
    <data>
        <variable name="fragment" type="com.yourpath.fragments.MyListFragment" />
        <variable name="iBindingRecyclerView" type="com.yourpath.interfaces.IBindingRecyclerView"/>
    </data>
```

Next up the Generic use everywhere all the time for all recycler views lol.

STEP 5 GENERIC ADAPTER FOR MOST SITUATIONS (COPY PASTE EXACTLY AS IS)

You can remove interface callbacks that you don't use of course.

```
class BindingRecyclerViewAdapter<T> : RecyclerView.Adapter<BindingRecyclerViewAdapter.BindingHolder>(), View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // MEMBERS
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private val MODEL_TAG = -124
    private val MODEL_POSITION_TAG = -125
    private var mRowLayoutResourceId: Int = 0
    private var mBindingModelId: Int = 0
    private var mActionButtonId: Int = 0
    private var mHasActionButton: Boolean = false
    private var mList: ObservableArrayList<*>? = null
    private lateinit var mIBindingRecyclerView: IBindingRecyclerView<T>
    private var mIBindingRecyclerViewPlus: IBindingRecyclerViewPlus<T>? = null


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // PROPERTIES
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /**
     * This is now how the interface needs to be set. This is taken care of in the @BindingAdapter
     * method "bind:rcvInterface" (BindingAdapterMethods). I also decided to take care of setting the
     * rowLayoutResourceId here, more as a "might as well" sort of thing, but also preventing the chance
     * of a null ref exception if we were to use mIBindingRecyclerView.getRowLayoutResourceId() and
     * mIBindingRecyclerView was null. Same goes for bindingModelId.
     * @param iBindingRecyclerView
     */
    fun setIBindingRecyclerView(iBindingRecyclerView: IBindingRecyclerView<*>, iBindingRecyclerViewPlus: IBindingRecyclerViewPlus<*>? = null) {
        mIBindingRecyclerView = iBindingRecyclerView as IBindingRecyclerView<T>
        mRowLayoutResourceId = iBindingRecyclerView.getRowLayoutResourceId()
        mBindingModelId = iBindingRecyclerView.getBindingModelId()
        mActionButtonId = iBindingRecyclerView.getActionButtonResourceId()
        mHasActionButton = mActionButtonId > 0
        mIBindingRecyclerViewPlus = iBindingRecyclerViewPlus as IBindingRecyclerViewPlus<T>?
    }
    /**
     * This is how the list is set and any changes made will be notified here. If notifyDataSetChanged()
     * is not called here, then the view will not be updated with the list changes. Setting the list gets
     * taken care of in the @BindingAdapter method "bind:rcvList" (BindingAdapterMethods). Anytime the list
     * changes in the activity/fragment, it will trigger the "bind:rcvList" method, and that will call
     * setList(), thus updating the list and notifying data set changed which updates the view properly.
     * @param list
     */
    fun setList(list: ObservableArrayList<*>) {
        mList = list
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // BASE CLASS OVERRIDES
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BindingHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val viewDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<ViewDataBinding>(inflater, mRowLayoutResourceId, parent, false)
        return BindingHolder(viewDataBinding)
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BindingHolder, position: Int) {
        val model = mList!![position]
        holder.binding.setVariable(mBindingModelId, model)
        holder.binding.root.setTag(MODEL_TAG, model)
        holder.binding.root.setTag(MODEL_POSITION_TAG, position)
        holder.binding.root.setOnClickListener(this)
        holder.binding.root.setOnLongClickListener(this)

        if(mIBindingRecyclerViewPlus != null){
            mIBindingRecyclerViewPlus?.onRowBinding(model as T, position, holder)
        }

        if (mHasActionButton) {
            val btnAction = holder.binding.root.findViewById<View>(mActionButtonId)
            btnAction.setTag(MODEL_TAG, model)
            btnAction.setTag(MODEL_POSITION_TAG, position)
            onActionClick(btnAction, holder)
        }

        holder.binding.executePendingBindings()
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return if (mList == null) 0 else mList!!.size
    }


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // CLICK LISTENERS
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        val model = v.getTag(MODEL_TAG) as T
        val position = v.getTag(MODEL_POSITION_TAG) as Int
        mIBindingRecyclerView.onItemClick(model, position)
    }
    override fun onLongClick(v: View): Boolean {
        val model = v.getTag(MODEL_TAG) as T
        val position = v.getTag(MODEL_POSITION_TAG) as Int
        mIBindingRecyclerView.onItemLongClick(model, position)
        return true
    }
    fun onActionClick(btnAction: View, holder: BindingHolder) {
        btnAction.setOnClickListener {
            val model = btnAction.getTag(MODEL_TAG) as T
            val position = btnAction.getTag(MODEL_POSITION_TAG) as Int
            mIBindingRecyclerView.onActionItemClick(model, position, holder)
        }
    }


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // SCOPED CLASSES
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    class BindingHolder(var binding: ViewDataBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

}
```

Last Step
Using it :).

STEP 6 BIND YOUR RECYCLERVIEW

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp_20"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dp_20"
        app:bindRcvInterface="@{iBindingRecyclerView}"
        app:bindRcvList="@{fragment.getYourListItemModelList}"/>
```

NOTE* you don't specify the () symbol, just use it like shown above.

So the good news, is most of this is one time setup. aka use it all over in your app.

OH YEAH and Optional, it is in my code, but may do your own variation for handling the look of the recycler view.

THE VERTICALITEMDECORATOR

```
class VerticalItemDecoration (private var spacingInPx: Int) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

/*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// ITEM DECORATION OVERRIDES
*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
    outRect.bottom = spacingInPx
}
```

}

Reusable Items include:

- interface
- jvm static adapter
- recycler view adapter
- Vertical Decorator

So really you are just implementing the interface, supplying the list in the form of an observable list, set your variables in your onCreate, and putting the two lines in your xml and repeat :).

Happy Coding. Hope this helps.